# Где можно глянуть РЕАЛЬНУЮ статистику использования браузеров?

Tags: кроссбраузерность

собственно, сабж
в гугле везде разные циферки почему-то вылазят.
приемущественно, конечно, интересует, как много народу ещё пользуются ИЕ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сайт для всей России смотри смотри открытые счетчики - Vk, [lenta.ru](http://lenta.ru) и другие.
Если сайт рассчитан на регион конкретный - найди сайт крупный с открытой статистикой и смотри у них.